# Job is Storing History But 'Include Step Output in History' is not Checked

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, jobs

I have a SQL Server Agent Job. The 'Include step output in history' checkbox is **unchecked**. However, when I right-click oon the job and select 'View History', I can see that it is tracking step output.

There is just the one step on the job.

Why is this? Am I missing some setting?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That check box does not prevent job step history from being recorded/stored. SQL Server is going to do all this by default and that I know of you cannot turn it off.

The check box referenced is for telling SQL Agent to store `additional` or `more detailed` job step output. It would store this information to `msdb.dbo.sysjobstepslogs`. Which from my testing just checking that box alone does not do anything. You would still find the table empty if you queried it. Once I also checked `Log to table`, ran the job again, and then it showed a record for the job step.

This would enabled on a job that runs `DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP` command for a database:
[image]

Comment: Step output in this case means all standard output from processes called in the job step - Output from for example: queries, powershell scripts; executables. The job history table will always include time, error and limited output the include step output option starts verbose loggin: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1411/verbose-sql-server-agent-logging/